# How to restart Dramatiq in Windows on code update or server restart?

Tags: python, django, windows-server, dramatiq

I am using Django-Dramatiq with Dramatiq and RabbitMQ.  I have it all working, but I am not sure the proper way to deploy to a Windows Server.  If the server restarts, how do I make sure that the workers start again?  If I deploy new code changes, what is the best way to stop and start the workers again to get the changes?

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/winsw/winsw

It can manage and monitor windows processes for you which you can use to auto restart workers, rabbit, your app etc. For code changes you need to tell it to restart the processes manually.

```
winsw restart [<path-to-config>] [--no-elevate]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nsssm to run it as a windows service: https://nssm.cc/. It supports autorestart on server restarts